# Powershell script to export Microsoft Access query or table into CSV file

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-access

I've got the beginnings of a basic script. Ideally, it would run a query in Access, then take the results of a query and enter into a CSV, but it doesn't seem to be writing anything into my CSVs (although its modified date/time is being altered).

What am I missing?

```
$Acc = New-Object –Com Access.Application

$Acc.OpenCurrentDataBase("H:\TEST.mdb")

#Runs the query
$Acc.DoCmd.OpenQuery("Query1")

#Dealing with results
$Results = $Acc.DoCmd.OpenQuery("Query1")

$Results | Select-Object $Results | Export-Csv -Path H:\test.csv -Delimiter ";"
```

I have also tried ending with this instead:

```
$Results | Out-File -Append H:\test2.csv -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Is `$Results` empty?

Comment: No, if I run the query manually it does produce at least few results.

Comment: @glass_kites Is the `$results` a string array or something that can be represented as one? `$results.GetType().Fullname`. `$Results | Select-Object $Results` seems odd to me. If $results is an object then can you just remove the select altogether?

Comment: You are using the COM object for access. What you've done is equivalent of opening a .doc file in word. You may wanna try something like this https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2009/08/13/hey-scripting-guy-can-i-query-a-microsoft-access-database-with-a-windows-powershell-script/

Comment: The output of my query (which I'm naming $Results) ends up as a Datasheet View of a 8 column table in Access. If that helps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `OpenQuery()` method just opens the query in Access. It doesn't return the query results. You can use the [`TransferText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958.aspx) method for saving the resultset of a query definition as CSV:

```
$acc.DoCmd.Transfertext(2, [Type]::Missing, 'Query1', 'H:\test.csv', $true)
```

Comment: I tried this line of code. It does print to a file but two small issues for me . 1. i want to change the delimitter from comma to a tab and second, i want the double quotes around values to be removed. SOrry for the late question to an old question